# Error in for-loop: FireFox claims missing parenthesis, but is not true. Issue with generic selector?

Tags: javascript, html, web, syntax, jquery-selectors

I'm getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

in my firefox console, pointing to the indicated line in this for loop:

```
for (var x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 8; y++) {                       
        if ($('#'x+','+y).hasClass('selected')) {   //<---error
            cell[x,y,0] = 'alive';
        } else {
            cell[x,y,0] = 'dead';
        }
    }
}
```

It seems FireFox is wrong with its claim that there's a missing paranthesis. Perhaps there is a problem with the selector on the line of the error? The generic selector is meant to point to a large number of html elements with ids in the form "x,y". Example: "12,4"

Comment: 1 - 0 in favor of Firefox :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse error in

```
$('#'x+','+y).
```

You're missing a `+`. It should be:

```
$('#' + x + ',' + y).
```

with whitespace for readability.

Comment: oh of course. darn cognitive fallacies making me consider hashtag to be special. Will accept answer once i'm allowed to by timer.